I have infinity redirection after keycloak login
I'm developing an application (spring boot + keycloak) and now I have a problem with authorization. When i enter all necessary users's data and click the login button, I have infinity redirection issue.
My urls
What url keycloak generate after authorization: http://localhost:8080/realms/free-party/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=auth-app&scope=auth%20microprofile-jwt%20openid&state=AksPBD4yPdRSF1uYaXe6qsGD2vKq6nxmVhAQKvuWRlk%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8090/login/oauth2/code/auth-app-authorization-code&nonce=ZJBl0KJbWrbK31kMTUhqkmFTpK3asAAoxZGUqpWmKCw
My application.yml
Big thank for you'r help
I've tried to change base url in keycloak configuration, add all Keycloak's urls in my application.yml file non of these ways didn't help
